# How to hide Google map details when using gmap-vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue application and am using gmap-vue to show information onf Google maps. I want to hide the POI markers on the map. I found out that you have to do that by changing the style, but I can't make it work with gmap-vue. Who can give me a hint?

The relevant part of my Vue app:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <gmap-map
      :center="marker"
      :zoom="13"
      ref="map"
      :options="mapOptions"
      class="map-container"
    >
      <gmap-marker
        :position="marker"
        icon="/images/iesmenke-vrijgemaakt-klein.png"
        title="De ijskar van de IJsmannetjes"
      >
      </gmap-marker>
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["area"],

  data() {
    return {
      marker: {
        lat: 51.33,
        lng: 6.14,
      },
      id: null,
      delay: 600000, //Ophalen nieuwe positie iedere 600 seconden
      ijskarlogo: {
        url: "/images/iesmenke-vrijgemaakt.png",
      },
      mapOptions: {
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        disableDefaultUi: false,
        clickableIcons: false,
        styles: {
          hide: [
            {
              featureType: "poi.business",
              stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did is using the $mapPromise function to directly access map, like in the example.

```
this.$refs.map.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
  map.setOptions({
        styles: [
          {
            featureType: 'poi.business',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }],
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'labels.icon',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }],
          },
        ]
      })
})
```